# git push heroku master fails to compile "rake aborted cannot load such file scss"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am running:

```
git push heroku master
```

On an already created branch and getting a compile error. We are not using SCSS in our code, just plain old CSS. Not sure why we are getting this error, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sidenote: That file did exist at one time but we deleted it. Is it somehow being regenerated by Heroku?

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
###### WARNING:
       Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows.
       Bundler will do a full resolve so native gems are handled properly.
       This may result in unexpected gem versions being used in your app.
       In rare occasions Bundler may not be able to resolve your dependencies at all.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-windows-gemfile

-----> Installing dependencies using 1.6.3
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
       Resolving dependencies...
       Installing i18n 0.6.11
       Installing rake 10.3.2
       Installing minitest 5.4.1
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.4
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Installing builder 3.2.2
       Installing json 1.8.1
       Installing mime-types 1.25.1
       Installing arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
       Using bundler 1.6.3
       Installing polyglot 0.3.5
       Installing rack 1.5.2
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.8.0
       Installing execjs 2.2.1
       Installing hike 1.2.3
       Installing thor 0.19.1
       Installing multi_json 1.10.1
       Installing tilt 1.4.1
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
       Installing treetop 1.4.15
       Installing rack-test 0.6.2
       Installing rdoc 4.1.2
       Installing coffee-script 2.3.0
       Installing uglifier 2.5.3
       Installing sprockets 2.12.2
       Installing activesupport 4.1.4
       Installing mail 2.5.4
       Installing sdoc 0.4.1
       Installing activemodel 4.1.4
       Installing actionview 4.1.4
       Installing jbuilder 2.1.3
       Installing actionpack 4.1.4
       Installing actionmailer 4.1.4
       Installing activerecord 4.1.4
       Installing railties 4.1.4
       Installing sprockets-rails 2.1.4
       Installing coffee-rails 4.0.1
       Installing jquery-rails 3.1.2
       Installing turbolinks 2.3.0
       Installing rails 4.1.4
       Installing pg 0.17.1
       Your bundle is complete!
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       It was installed into ./vendor/bundle
       Post-install message from rdoc:
       Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
       <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
       = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
       >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
       Bundle completed (18.80s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:12.972254 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/homepage-tiles/350x200-d03cdabc223d07ad0141a57639e52979.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:12.974874 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114-1df9aad1bb3cfdb87fe4c54074796aea.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:12.977500 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-114x114-f06086651c5ed0af5acebf8c5a58048f.psd
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:12.979535 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72-b9cafa424c2437f3eee68ec0ad2a8791.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:12.981598 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-72x72-9cb7f07677ba05eac34a7cbae31b45ed.psd
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:12.988824 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-ba85f3fe10e9e7ac74d99905c601ad9a.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:12.990929 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/apple-touch-icon-a33a208ee97d3093e6c1ebbb3d1fc7ff.psd
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:12.992823 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/aside-e305fedfc5c6ce4c53d6f6fc6bbe53bc.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:12.994762 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/aside@2x-e9c58ec1da806f7f54724f7c4dcb936f.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:12.997644 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/cart-add-f2064d331351207371d5fbf19dff94f7.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.000694 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/cart-add@2x-72ed21dc2273de797b4a819ab439e33e.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.002611 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/cart-added-70998d4fa38c3a90e79078251b0975a3.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.004649 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/cart-added@2x-3a8a30db75becd70be5c922edd243882.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.006580 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/cart-5fcc677083249733e867061ce57c71bd.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.011868 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/cart@2x-8f6d4dc8ceb8496ddcb59e1bee0e94bd.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.013759 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/close-search-black-5502be39728bff08eea64141feb849d2.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.018251 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/close-search-cd909fe38d7ec1092cc5e91c7c9380c6.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.024954 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/comment-children-line-71897de7e6f12d759e6db15bf0904849.jpg
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.027778 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/dropdown-arrows-black-6917e0b23ac4fa5d46e0e5c3cfb7aa22.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.029669 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/dropdown-arrows-13c1e451732c99545ee6276df10a54a8.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.031568 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/favicon-be1847a32ebd3b54a253a25957486737.ico
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.033661 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/favicon-311233403ae14664892d476477615077.psd
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.085302 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/heart-white-bg-6b1a07b72f7e54483324bda6484a2764.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.087248 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/heart-white-bg@2x-079af0fc2ec3dc989ead5a2b506f29e7.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.089380 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/heart-e0ba8b879f241e7178a6450e1868dfee.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.091167 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/heart@2x-c7610bf9d5d7696dacbaafcc14ad5336.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.093756 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/jplayer-667c08ccdc3abb561c7ba983de6ab3ab.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.095597 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/link-1dd9b1479aae7f419f6930e26db2602c.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.097452 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/link@2x-296f333a87d0b8f0ef97645567d05752.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.099353 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/loading-white-bg-864cd598365d4d71f660c5ba1334cb64.gif
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.101518 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/loading-f206d0a710d0c8375c665d43ab07b25e.gif
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.103488 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/loading-c4aa55b464271b33700c1d5b84e05d70.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.105471 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/mag-glass-black-27aa2c2cd5119d5e90c0ff9c508b6e11.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.107311 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/mag-glass-black@2x-d932e6d03f426710d320c3a809fcf329.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.109102 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/mag-glass-mobile-7ce5b127019dee5ba7689100809c91f2.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.110699 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/mag-glass-mobile@2x-de1336cecb5538a9c6a402bd880478e4.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.112369 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/mag-glass-71fbc2e4610cb7835c4ffa55a442c7a8.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.114068 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/mag-glass@2x-e5775f805dc8986a035309962383ddd4.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.115615 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/nectar-loading-9713a13942060099648353be46560b9a.gif
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.117179 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/play-c560f1319fce1c9d993886709d7e836e.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.118720 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/portfolio-arrows-d12d3c99c86fe1337d6d3780c57e3e02.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.120289 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/portfolio-arrows@2x-5bd56dc1d7be571073f7112ee2b6f57a.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.121827 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/quote-f3fdf4c12ec5b937473196edc24054f7.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.123372 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/quote@2x-93a33cc02af0b085b85f709a9f7bf27c.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.125164 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/quotes-fb6882af9d3c06672a3a87d6df015817.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.126872 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/quotes@2x-2cf8168ebb1be90c3785b3f96a28ca6d.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.128643 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/recent-comment-dark-4e0a575d43bc92e0ad575ccb92781d6d.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.132903 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/recent-comment-808e91d27cdfdbeec14a3c1c51d1e5bf.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.134534 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/responsive-dropdown-arrows-ef91325ca9d69d8a0e10056868b9d793.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.136305 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/slider-arrows-shadows-8490047c951e6807c0d3b9df7d7d918f.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.137951 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/slider-arrows-small-38d8c755c5481eeed8714e49ecfbc55e.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.139508 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/slider-arrows-97a32b23d16ddca6db9ddc0056f7642e.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.141196 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/slider-arrows@2x-5c89550da672b6c34cb847dae8e6e538.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.142734 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/behance-header-black-1571c6e942e73f5e0095b4ebf08d0f56.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.144324 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/behance-header-black@2x-904fdf9bfe488eacaea67fdcf4f58050.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.145841 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/behance-header-aa40bd2316e6afcdf913994b78a951b6.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.147391 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/behance-header@2x-f40e97889258e9144ff53146c4425c9d.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.149174 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/behance-7fb57d7119ddaf88c7b270e53e87105a.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.150861 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/behance@2x-5ebdaf2848e616d588c0f36de1bf8ce1.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.152869 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/facebook-share-c92b5c7ba5a5053eae419cee8d9a7a7f.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.154653 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/facebook-share@2x-0d544d68953b0c170002345855468005.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.156380 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/pinterest-share-90fc5c9a11bf3f36a7b623cbcf8f56b9.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.158461 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/pinterest-share@2x-9306a091853baefb579d0144e43732b6.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.160287 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/twitter-share-26f2064c7469e76b9e2b58b5163f0e15.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.162091 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/twitter-share@2x-ab48207319b9ad387bd957dba1e04779.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.163840 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/vimeo-header-black-822ecfe090cba7a958d2c160ef3402d0.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.165605 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/vimeo-header-black@2x-b19a300721e13086934ee731a755e290.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.167402 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/vimeo-header-235cf30054be50b36a28ea2dc9e31d72.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.169244 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/vimeo-header@2x-f05a0634c8ee2a1f39bf491fec73d70e.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.171084 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/vimeo-ccbb124c20a38a7b4c7d56c8483c141c.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.172897 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/social/vimeo@2x-a542a944c719ad6ded15bbb21c3d1622.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.184641 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/status-ef2e94fa3d13a12a0dd5689e5b231adb.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.186351 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/icons/status@2x-80f3e2ce2420d50b02eaed24473e3299.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.188485 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/logo-inverted-481d2df641b4acdf4239ebb1ceff605d.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.198691 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/logo-white-14944e72990ddcdfeff0d291a6808899.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:13.205518 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/logo-b3288936cd68cfdb5901e259581fa8a1.png
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:20.668838 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/application-f4c13f1688ea29de13f569fe2c069da7.js
       I, [2014-09-21T04:14:21.567383 #1040]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/public/assets/bootstrap.min-0e9b73211f2f677fed8db7791acc1d3f.js
       rake aborted!
       LoadError: cannot load such file -- sass
       (in /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/app/assets/stylesheets/static_pages.css.scss)
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:144:in `require_template_library'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/sass_template.rb:20:in `initialize_engine'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:56:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:196:in `new'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:196:in `block in evaluate'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.2/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
       /tmp/build_d8f1b999-1ae8-47bd-a95f-9b5ddaf38c19/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

Comment: Do you have sass in your Gemfile? I see no "sass" listed in your bundle install log from heroku.

Comment: Just to be sure, after deleting `/static_pages.css.scss`, did you add the deletion in git commit?

Answer (score 0):

Try precompiling your assets before pushing your code by running `rake assets:precompile`.